# Get last completed jobs execution context spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to fetch execution context of last completed job. Below is the code:

```
@Component
public class MyJobDataReader implements ItemReader<MyDbEntity>, StepExecutionListener {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jobService")
    JobService jobService;

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        Collection<JobExecution> jobExecutions = null;
        try {
            jobExecutions = jobService.listJobExecutionsForJob("myjob", 0, jobService.countJobExecutionsForJob("myjob"));
        } catch (NoSuchJobException e) {
            //log
        }

        JobExecution lastCompletedJobExecution =
                jobExecutions
                .stream()
                .filter(param -> param.getExitStatus().getExitCode().equals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        Long myExecutionContextParam = 
                lastCompletedJobExecution
                .getExecutionContext()
                .getLong(contextParam);
    }
}
```

But I am getting the `myExecutionContextParam` also null , even though I see the value in `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT` table for the fetched job execution.

Comment: The code you shared does not compile, it should implement the method `read` from the `ItemReader` interface. Moreover, `MyJobDataReader` should be registered as a listener in the step so that `beforeStep` is invoked. Otherwise you need to implement `ItemStreamReader` and it will be automatically registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `jobService.listJobExecutionsForJob` was returning a JobExecution with few fields , then I had to call `jobService.getJobExecution(jobExecutionId)` to get a fully enriched JobExecution

Comment: I'm getting a "Cannot load execution context for job execution" error - any thoughts on that?

Comment: Could you please share the full working code. I am interested in looking at the JobService class.